# In R I wish to find the latest xlsx file in a folder and then import the data from that file

Tags: r, csv, import, xlsx

In R I wish to find the latest xlsx file in a folder and then import the data from that file. All files have the same format. I just keep getting blank. Please advise correct code.

```
CompanyFileNames <- file.info(list.files 
                              (path = "Y:/...Data", 
                               pattern = "*port.xlsx", 
                               full.names = T))

CompanyFilelatest <- subset(CompanyFileNames, mtime == max(mtime))

CompanyFilelatest <- CompanyFilelatest[0]

Companymonthly <- sapply(CompanyFilelatest, 
              read_excel, simplify=FALSE) 
              %>% bind_rows(.id = "id")                         

write.csv(Companymonthly, "Companymonthly.csv")
```

Comment: C:/.../20190120 port.xlsx
C:/.../20190222 port.xlsx
C:/.../20190324 port.xlsx

Comment: File names look like above

Comment: Data looks like ID Name Ref category  date
1 House Ltd 1001 P 14/Dec/2018
2 Court Ltd 1002 D 05/Dec/2018
3 Garden Ltd 1003 W 25/Jul/2018

Comment: Try that again...Data looks like ID Name Ref category  date
1 House Ltd 1001 P 14/Dec/2018
2 Court Ltd 1002 D 05/Dec/2018
3 Garden Ltd 1003 W 25/Jul/2018

Comment: you should add all of those comments to the actual question itself instead of adding them as a comment.

Comment: Apologies hit enter!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is the filepath of the latest file, which is stored as the rowname of `CompanyFilelatest`. Extract the file path with `rownames()` and then this should work.

```r
CompanyFileNames <- file.info(list.files 
                              (path = getwd(), 
                                pattern = "*.xlsx", 
                                full.names = T))

CompanyFilelatest <- subset(CompanyFileNames, mtime == max(mtime))

CompanyFilelatest <- rownames(CompanyFilelatest) # use rownames not subseting with 0

Companymonthly <- sapply(CompanyFilelatest, 
                         read_excel, simplify=FALSE) %>% bind_rows(.id = "id")                         

write.csv(Companymonthly, "Companymonthly.csv")
```